# Can I override a Directive's host manipulation in the hosting element?

Tags: angular

Some third party code has:

```
@Directive({
selector: '.something',
host: {'[attr.tabindex]': 0}
})
```

I need the directive, but I want tabindex to be -1 on the host element. If a directive manipulates a host attribute like this, is there a way to override it? (It cannot be overridden by accessing the host element via a `ViewChild` and changing the attribute via `ngAfterViewInit`.)

UPDATE

First off, a bit more context. The third-party directive was selecting based on the HTML class of the host element: `<div class="something"></div>`. Based on @yash's useful advice, I made my own attribute directive:

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[bandaid]'
})
export class BandaidDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private elementRef: ElementRef
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // after the current change detection cycle, remove the host from the tabindex
        setTimeout(() => this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'tabindex', '-1'), 0);
    }
}
```

It basically resets the tabindex attribute after the third party directive has processed. To apply the bandaid: `<div class="something" bandaid></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Renderer2` or `ElementRef` instead of `ViewChild`. You can access the html element of the directive by using one of them.

```
constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
) {}
...
this.renderer.setAttribute(...);
this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute(...);
```